# 3D to 4D surface fitter converter

Tags: python, numpy

I recently wrote this bit of code while trying to convert a 3D surface fitter to a 4D one. The solution works and I didn't want to leave the next guy to grind out the solution so I made the code as clean as I could and posted it. I'm still not super stoked with it though. How could I have made this cleaner?

See [Modify surface code to solve for 4 dimensions instead of 3 [edited]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113010/modify-surface-code-to-solve-for-4-dimensions-instead-of-3-edited) for the full background and post.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


class Surface4D:
    def __init__(self, order, a, b, c, z):
        # Setting initial attributes
        self.order = order
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.z = z
        # Setting surface attributes
        self.surface = self._fit_surface()
        self.aa = None
        self.bb = None
        self._sample_surface_grid()
        # Setting graph attributes
        self.surface_render = None
        self.axis_3d = None

    # Start black magic math
    def _abc_powers(self):
        powers = itertools.product(range(self.order + 1), range(self.order + 1), range(self.order + 1))
        return [tup for tup in powers if sum(tup) <= self.order]

    def _fit_surface(self):
        ncols = (self.order + 1)**3
        G = np.zeros((self.a.size, ncols))
        ijk = self._abc_powers()
        for idx, (i,j,k) in enumerate(ijk):
            G[:,idx] = self.a**i * self.b**j * self.c**k
        m, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(G, self.z, rcond=None)
        return m

    def get_z_values(self, a, b, c):
        ijk = self._abc_powers()
        z = np.zeros_like(a)
        for s, (i,j,k) in zip(self.surface, ijk):
            z += s * a**i * b**j * c**k
        return z
    # End black magic math

    def render_4d_flow(self):
        # Set up the layout of the graph
        fig = plt.figure()
        self.axis_3d = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0.1,0.2,0.8,0.7])
        slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.05])
        self.axis_3d.set_xlabel('X data')
        self.axis_3d.set_ylabel('Y data')
        self.axis_3d.set_zlabel('Z data')

        # Plot the point cloud and initial surface
        self.axis_3d.scatter(self.a, self.b, self.z, color='red', zorder=0)
        zz = self.get_z_values(self.aa, self.bb, 1)
        self.surface_render = self.axis_3d.plot_surface(self.aa, self.bb, zz, zorder=10, alpha=0.4, color="b")

        # Setup the slider behavior
        slider_start_step = self.c.min()
        slider_max_steps = self.c.max()
        slider = Slider(slider_ax, 'time', slider_start_step, slider_max_steps , valinit=slider_start_step)
        slider.on_changed(self._update)

        plt.show()
        input("Once youre done, hit any enter to continue.")

    def _update(self, val):
        self.surface_render.remove()
        zz = self.get_z_values(self.aa, self.bb, val)
        self.surface_render = self.axis_3d.plot_surface(self.aa, self.bb, zz, zorder=10, alpha=0.4, color="b")

    def _sample_surface_grid(self):
        na, nb = 40, 40
        aa, bb = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(self.a.min(), self.a.max(), na), 
                            np.linspace(self.b.min(), self.b.max(), nb))
        self.aa = aa
        self.bb = bb

def noisify_array(one_dim_array, randomness_multiplier):
    listOfNewValues = []
    range = abs(one_dim_array.min()-one_dim_array.max())
    for item in one_dim_array:
        # What percentage are we shifting the point dimension by
        shift = np.random.randint(0, 101)
        shiftPercent = shift/100
        shiftPercent = shiftPercent * randomness_multiplier

        # Is that shift positive or negative
        shiftSignIndex = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        shifSignOption = [-1, 1]
        shiftSign = shifSignOption[shiftSignIndex]

        # Shift it
        newNoisyPosition = item + (range * (shiftPercent * shiftSign))
        listOfNewValues.append(newNoisyPosition)
    return np.array(listOfNewValues)


def generate_data():
    # Define our range for each dimension
    x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 20)
    y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 20)
    w = [1, 2, 3]

    # Populate each dimension
    a,b,c,z = [],[],[],[]
    for X in x:
        for Y in y:
            for W in w:
                a.append(X)
                b.append(Y)
                c.append(W)
                z.append((1 * X ** 4) + (2 * Y ** 3) + (X * Y ** W) + (4 * X) + (5 * Y))

    # Convert them to arrays
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    c = np.array(c)
    z = np.array(z)

    return [a, b, c, z]

def main(order):
    # Make the data
    a,b,c,z = generate_data()

    # Show the pure data and best fit
    surface_pure_data = Surface4D(order, a, b, c, z)
    surface_pure_data.render_4d_flow()

    # Add some noise to the data
    a = noisify_array(a, 0.10)
    b = noisify_array(b, 0.10)
    c = noisify_array(c, 0.10)
    z = noisify_array(z, 0.10)

    # Show the noisy data and best fit
    surface_noisy_data = Surface4D(order, a, b, c, z)
    surface_noisy_data.render_4d_flow()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------

orderForSurfaceFit = 5
main(orderForSurfaceFit)
```

[Edit: Clarified that the 3d to 4d conversion is solved]

Comment: @BCdotWEB, to me, `Trying` might indicate the code isn't working as expected.

Comment: To be clear, I'm no longer trying. The code works as expected, I'm just looking for feedback on how to make it cleaner. For example, I recently found out that the convention for 4 dimensions is x,y,w,z so to make it more readable/intuitive for those with a background in 4d math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add PEP484 type hints to all of your signatures, and your members whose type can't be inferred during construction.

`_abc_powers` need not return a list: it can return a generator, which will (a) avoid materialisation to memory and (b) avoid the creation of a hidden, inner generator function.

PEP8 asks for all of these figures:

```
0.1,0.2,0.8,0.7
```

to have spaces after the comma.

This line:

```
    self.axis_3d = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0.1,0.2,0.8,0.7])
```

causes `matplotlib` to complain in runtime:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Axes3D(fig) adding itself to the figure is deprecated since 3.4. Pass the keyword argument auto_add_to_figure=False and use fig.add_axes(ax) to suppress this warning. The default value of auto_add_to_figure will change to False in mpl3.5 and True values will no longer work in 3.6.  This is consistent with other Axes classes.
  self.axis_3d = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7])
```

so you should fix this.

Typo: `youre` -> `you're`.

It's not a great idea to `input()` and wait to continue. If the user closes the plot window, you can trust that they're done, right? Why not just create both views, issue one `plt.show()`, and when both figure windows are closed allow the program to exit normally?

`listOfNewValues` by PEP8 should be `list_of_new_values` and similar for other variables in your code.

Your `generate_data` should be rewritten to be vectorised; none of those loops are necessary.

The `z.append` expression doesn't need any inner parens due to order of operations.

Your `return [a, b, c, z]` should not use a list literal, and should use the more conventional tuple instead.

A light refactor touching on a couple of topics above, mainly to demonstrate type hints, is:

```
import itertools
from typing import Optional, Iterator

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection


class Surface4D:
    def __init__(self, order: int, a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, c: np.ndarray, z: np.ndarray) -> None:
        # Setting initial attributes
        self.order = order
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.z = z

        # Setting surface attributes
        self.surface = self._fit_surface()
        self.aa: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
        self.bb: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
        self._sample_surface_grid()

        # Setting graph attributes
        self.surface_render: Optional[Poly3DCollection] = None
        self.axis_3d: Optional[Axes3D] = None

    # Start black magic math
    def _abc_powers(self) -> Iterator[tuple[int, int, int]]:
        powers = itertools.product(range(self.order + 1), range(self.order + 1), range(self.order + 1))
        for tup in powers:
            if sum(tup) <= self.order:
                yield tup

    def _fit_surface(self) -> np.ndarray:
        ncols = (self.order + 1)**3
        G = np.zeros((self.a.size, ncols))
        ijk = self._abc_powers()
        for idx, (i, j, k) in enumerate(ijk):
            G[:, idx] = self.a**i * self.b**j * self.c**k
        m, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(G, self.z, rcond=None)
        return m

    def get_z_values(self, a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, c: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        ijk = self._abc_powers()
        z = np.zeros_like(a)
        for s, (i, j, k) in zip(self.surface, ijk):
            z += s * a**i * b**j * c**k
        return z
    # End black magic math

    def render_4d_flow(self) -> None:
        # Set up the layout of the graph
        fig = plt.figure()
        self.axis_3d = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7])
        slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.05])
        self.axis_3d.set_xlabel('X data')
        self.axis_3d.set_ylabel('Y data')
        self.axis_3d.set_zlabel('Z data')

        # Plot the point cloud and initial surface
        self.axis_3d.scatter(self.a, self.b, self.z, color='red', zorder=0)
        zz = self.get_z_values(self.aa, self.bb, 1)
        self.surface_render = self.axis_3d.plot_surface(self.aa, self.bb, zz, zorder=10, alpha=0.4, color="b")

        # Setup the slider behavior
        slider_start_step = self.c.min()
        slider_max_steps = self.c.max()
        slider = Slider(slider_ax, 'time', slider_start_step, slider_max_steps , valinit=slider_start_step)
        slider.on_changed(self._update)

        plt.show()
        input("Once you're done, hit any enter to continue.")

    def _update(self, val) -> None:
        self.surface_render.remove()
        zz = self.get_z_values(self.aa, self.bb, val)
        self.surface_render = self.axis_3d.plot_surface(self.aa, self.bb, zz, zorder=10, alpha=0.4, color="b")

    def _sample_surface_grid(self) -> None:
        na, nb = 40, 40
        aa, bb = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(self.a.min(), self.a.max(), na),
                             np.linspace(self.b.min(), self.b.max(), nb))
        self.aa = aa
        self.bb = bb


def noisify_array(one_dim_array, randomness_multiplier) -> np.ndarray:
    listOfNewValues = []
    range = abs(one_dim_array.min()-one_dim_array.max())
    for item in one_dim_array:
        # What percentage are we shifting the point dimension by
        shift = np.random.randint(0, 101)
        shiftPercent = shift/100
        shiftPercent = shiftPercent * randomness_multiplier

        # Is that shift positive or negative
        shiftSignIndex = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        shifSignOption = [-1, 1]
        shiftSign = shifSignOption[shiftSignIndex]

        # Shift it
        newNoisyPosition = item + (range * (shiftPercent * shiftSign))
        listOfNewValues.append(newNoisyPosition)
    return np.array(listOfNewValues)


def generate_data() -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # a
    np.ndarray,  # b
    np.ndarray,  # c
    np.ndarray,  # z
]:
    # Define our range for each dimension
    x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 20)
    y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 20)
    w = [1, 2, 3]

    # Populate each dimension
    a, b, c, z = [], [], [], []
    for X in x:
        for Y in y:
            for W in w:
                a.append(X)
                b.append(Y)
                c.append(W)
                z.append(X**4 + 2*Y**3 + X*Y**W + 4*X + 5*Y)

    # Convert them to arrays
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    c = np.array(c)
    z = np.array(z)

    return a, b, c, z


def main(order: int) -> None:
    # Make the data
    a, b, c, z = generate_data()

    # Show the pure data and best fit
    surface_pure_data = Surface4D(order, a, b, c, z)
    surface_pure_data.render_4d_flow()

    # Add some noise to the data
    a = noisify_array(a, 0.10)
    b = noisify_array(b, 0.10)
    c = noisify_array(c, 0.10)
    z = noisify_array(z, 0.10)

    # Show the noisy data and best fit
    surface_noisy_data = Surface4D(order, a, b, c, z)
    surface_noisy_data.render_4d_flow()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------

orderForSurfaceFit = 5
main(orderForSurfaceFit)
```